# How to get the course ID for Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

I'm trying to use [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom), I've read through [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started), and the course ID is used for basically everything, but they never explained where to find the course ID for a course.

It also seems like when you create a course, the function would return the course ID, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get the course ID for courses that already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the quickstart page for the documentation (https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/python), you can run a piece of code to list the first 10 courses the user has access to with their credentials. You can then add a `print(course['id'])` statement whilst iterating through the courses to print the id of the courses you have retrieved. The python example is shown below

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Classroom API.
    Prints the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Classroom API
    results = service.courses().list(pageSize=10).execute()
    courses = results.get('courses', [])

    if not courses:
        print('No courses found.')
    else:
        print('Courses:')
        for course in courses:
            print(course['name'])
            print(course['id'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in nodejs/javascript to retrieve all classroom

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const classroom = google.classroom('v1');
const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses"
];
google.options({
  auth: client,
});
//retrieve all classroom
async function getClassroom() {
  try {
    const res = await classroom.courses.list(
      // {
      //   pageSize: 10,
      //   pageToken: "",
      // }
    );
    console.log(res.data, "res");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error.message,);
  }
}
```

Note: The client is my preferred authorization method